# ¿Cómo se obtiene el valor dentro de un Picker en react-native?

Tags: react-native

Quisiera saber si alguien sabe cómo obtener el valor de la opción seleccionada dentro del picker para poder realizar operaciones dependiendo de la opción.

```
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
```

Esa es una parte del código

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien que quieres indicar con la parte del código proporcionada: `[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]` pero puedes aplicar lógica tras la selección de una opción en la función que uses para 'settear' el estado. Por ejemplo:

```
const PickerExample = () => {

  const [user,setUser] = useState('');

    const updateUser = (optionPicked) => {

      if(optionPicked=='perro'){
        optionPicked = optionPicked + ' y gato';
      }

      setUser(optionPicked);
   };


 return (
         <View>
            <Picker 
            selectedValue = {user} 
            onValueChange = {updateUser}>
               <Picker.Item label = "Opción 1 - casa" value = "casa" />
               <Picker.Item label = "Opción 2 - perro" value = "perro" />
               <Picker.Item label = "Opción 3 - coche" value = "coche" />
            </Picker>

            <Text style = {styles.text}>{user}</Text>
         </View>
      )
}
```

Puedes jugar con el código en el siguiente snack: [Link](https://snack.expo.io/SySoPa7YH)

Espero que te sea de ayuda.